# Created variations for products (error)

Tags: commerce

Good evening, I created variations for products and when I add references to the display product, I get the following error "error message The Data 1 uses tokens (tokens) following invalid: [node : field-product: commerce_price] ".
Look at the setting in the screenshot below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a field with multiple options, you need to use a delta. So if your token looks like this:

`node:field_product:commerce_price`

It should include a delta after the field name:

`node:field_product:0:commerce_price`

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I do not know how to do this. Can you explain me how to change the view without broken my field?

Comment: when I want to edit a node, it shows me the same error everywhere. Would you please answer ? "error message The Data 1 uses tokens (tokens) following invalid: [node : field-product: commerce_price] "